# C++ -- Is there an implicit cast here from Fred* to auto_ptr<Fred>?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, auto-ptr

I saw the following code,

```
#include <new>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class Fred;  // Forward declaration
typedef  auto_ptr<Fred>  FredPtr;

class Fred {
public:
  static FredPtr create(int i)
  { 
    return new Fred(i); // Is there an implicit casting here? If not, how can we return
                        // a Fred* with return value as FredPtr?
  }
private:
  Fred(int i=10)      : i_(i)    { }
  Fred(const Fred& x) : i_(x.i_) { }
  int i_;
};
```

Please see the question listed in function create.

Thank you

// Updated based on comments

Yes, the code cannot pass the VC8.0
error C2664: 'std::auto_ptr<_Ty>::auto_ptr(std::auto_ptr<_Ty> &) throw()' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Fred *' to 'std::auto_ptr<_Ty> &'

The code was copied from the C++ FAQ 12.15.

However, after making the following changes,

```
replace 
  return new Fred(i);
with
  return auto_ptr<Fred>(new Fred(i));
```

This code can pass the VC8.0 compiler. But I am not sure whether or not this is a correct fix.

Comment: Did this code compile?  Or did you just see it?

Comment: That is the correct fix.  Yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::auto_ptr` does have a constructor that takes a raw pointer as its argument, but that constructor is `explicit` and cannot be used as a converting constructor.

This code will not compile.

Comment: Having implicit conversion to an `auto_ptr` would be pretty insane considering the ownership semantics of `auto_ptr`

Comment: Yah, just checked to be sure right after posting my previous answer- doesn't compile for me too. Thanks

Comment: @ToAll, the original code in the book doesn't pass the compiler of VS8.0 -- thank you

Answer (score 3):

No, no such implicit conversion exists.  It turns out that this is actually a good thing, though.  For example, consider this code:

```
void MyFunction(const std::auto_ptr<Fred>& myFred) {
   /* ... do something to Fred. */
}

int main() {
    Fred* f = new Fred;
    MyFunction(f); // Not legal, but assume it is.
    f->doSomething();
}
```

Here, if you could pass a raw pointer to a Fred into MyFunction, then when that function returned and the temporary auto_ptr object was cleaned up, the memory you allocated in main() would be reclaimed, and the call to f->doSomething() would probably cause a segfault.  Making the auto_ptr constructor explicit is a safeguard against this; you don't want to accidentally acquire exclusive ownership of a resource when someone else thinks they already have that access.

Answer (score 0):

The fixed version of the code (`return std::auto_ptr<Fred>(new Fred())`) is correct and valid C++.  However, I'm not sure what the `create()` function buys you in that creating a `std::auto_ptr<T>` should be within the skill set of any C++ programmer.  Likewise, I'm not clear what `typedef`ing `std::auto_ptr<Fred>` to `FredPtr` buys you, other than a need to look up what a `FredPtr` really is.